# What 's different between "text frame" and "binary frame" in Websocket?

Tags: websocket

Text frame(opcode = 0x01) and Binary frame(opcode = 0x02) in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-29). What's different between them and which one is faster?

Comment: I have this question too..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some background and perhaps more familiarity in other realms, HTTP/1 relied on an unstructured plaintext protocol while HTTP/2 allowed for faster processing of messages through binary framing. Also, SMTP relies on text while TCP relies on a binary protocol. To sum up, text relies on ASCII ('Hello') while binary, although a confusing term, has no readable representation.  In JavaScript, `socket.send(new ArrayBuffer(8))` is a basic binary object and is one example of the format that can be sent.  This allocates a contiguous memory area of 8 bytes and pre-fills it with zeroes.

Hopefully this provides some good context.

`0x01` is hexadecimal number (denoted by `0x` and represents the integer 1) is the 4 bit opcode for the receiver (client or server) to know what type of "frame" it will receive.  UTF-8 is denoted by `0x01` and raw binary is denoted by `0x02`.

Raw binary will be much faster.  Imagine an architecture like so:

[image: Request Response Architecture]

If we send textual data (opcode `0x01`) via the Websocket, it must translate the received data at the proxy. Before the TCP server responds to the client message, it may have to translate the response to textual data.  Encoding binary data to ASCII text via base64 will increase the size of the message by 20-30%.

With an opcode of `0x02`, we can skip 2 steps in the whole request/response cycle and reduce the size of the message we are passing.  In short, we skip interpretation.  Moreover, the Websocket spec has UTF-8 validation rules.  The difference between text and binary might be 2x in favor of binary.